# Cannot read property 'remote' of null

Tags: node.js, noflo

Anyone know what causes this error when trying to use the noflo ui/editor?

I was attempting to run the editor using a local nodejs runtime, where the config was defined in a flowhub.json. I'm not clear whether it is sufficient to create the flowhub.json file and then start by executing "node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs", or whether you have to define command line parameters too. It works if I execute the same command but with my secret defined i.e. "node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --secret "

[image: Cannot read property 'remote' of null]

Comment: KJ, please read the [How To Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think this is a combination of working in different locations and as such having different ip addresses assigned to my laptop and forgetting to change the flowhub.json file when I startup. In effect the ui cannot connect to the websocket running my noflo-nodejs app. Can someone confirm that this makes sense?